# 301 error and search engine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know about 301 Error for website, I Binged about it and got the some overview about 301 Redirect Error.

I also got the code for ASP.NET redirect,

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
}
</script>
```

Comment: but i dont know how to implement it with my website?

Comment: how it helps with the search engine?

Comment: Just to confirm a 301 is not an 'error' - They are simply part of an initial response back to your client [web browser for example] to say "go here instead".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this code

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) { 
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"; 
    Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com"); 
}
```

Will create an HTTP response, that would tell client (browser) - "the resouce you've been looking to is not here any more, go and look to anthor place". Default behavior for browsers are indeed just go and look for given URI.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the spec for [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to fully understand what your exact question is here. But hopefully these help you,

[Google have some detail here on 301s](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633), including a video with Matt Cutt's (Google's head of WebSpam)
From an SEO standpoint, [SEOMoz's article here may be of use](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection).

As *alexanderb* says, the purpose of a 301 is to say 'the resource [page in most cases] is no longer at this address - instead go here.'